# Recurring events php

Tags: php, calendar

I am trying to allow a user to schedule an event in a calendar app similar to Google Calendar. I need to achieve an event that **Repeats every 3 week(s), ends after 2 occurrence(s)**

My current code is as follows:

```
$week = array('0'=>"Sunday","1"=>"Monday","2"=>"Tuesday","3"=>"Wednesday","4"=>"Thursday","5"=>"Friday","6"=>"Saturday");
                       $day = $week[$val];

$days = array(
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday',
    'Sunday',
  );

  $today = new DateTime($day);
  //$today = new DateTime('Friday'); //can set specific day if needed
//  print "Today is " . $today->format('l') . "\n";

  foreach($days as $day) {

    $diff = new DateTime($day);
    $diff = $diff->format('N') - $today->format('N');

    if($diff > 0) {
      //print "$day is $diff days in the future\n";
      //print "\n$diff days future\n";
       $st=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+'.($diff).' day',strtotime($s)));
    $et=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+'.$date_diff.'day',strtotime($s)));
    }
    elseif($diff < 0) {
      $diff = abs($diff);
     // print "$day is $diff days in the past\n";
     //  print "$diff days fast\n";
        $st=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+'.($diff).' day',strtotime($s)));
    $et=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+'.$date_diff.'day',strtotime($s)));
    }
    else {
    $st=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+'.$recordsave.' day',strtotime($s)));
    $et=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+'.$date_diff.'day',strtotime($s)));
    }
  }
```

Any idea friends?

Answer (score -1):

The only way to have PHP code fire is if a user is accessing it. I would suggest a [CRON job](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml) for this matter.

You could set a CRON schedule to run a particular line of code by calling that PHP page in a CRON job every 3 weeks for 2 weeks.

Comment: hey friend im developing like google calender apps , i need to display after user adding events

Comment: Your question was a tad vague, editing now to achieve your premise.